# Why does alt+left shift my virtual terminal left one?

Tags: 11.04, xorg, shortcut-keys, virtual-console

Normally I use alt+left key combo to go back one click in firefox but recently I noticed it's moving to vt6 instead. alt+right moves in the other direction among the vt screens. This is supposed to be disabled when X is running. Where is this configured and how do I turn it off?

**Edit:** I just tried out running a guest user session, and alt-left doesn't do this in unity. So this is probably something to do with my specific user, or metacity.

Comment: @nmagerko There is no indication that virtualization is being used. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console.

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: Are you using Compiz?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look in your compiz settings.  You can install compiz settings with the following command:

```
 sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then you'll want to open it up (just run `ccsm` from a terminal).  And go to the "Advanced Search" section.  Make sure the "Settings Value" box is check and search for the word "left" look through the results and you'll find the settings with the Alt+Left keybinding, then just simply disable it.

Comment: Also, look at **SystemMenu>Preferences>Keyboard:Keyboard Shortcuts**.

I prefer to use **alt** as a program-specific modifier and use **super** (Windows key) as my global modifier.

Comment: How does this relate to compiz? I get switched to vt2, and all VTs end up responding to alt+left and alt+right arrows. That is, I can use alt+right arrow to switch back to X11. Compiz is not managing anything outside X11.